# Conversão de números binarios em decimal

Tags: python, conversão, números-binários

Há alguma biblioteca no Python que posso utilizar para converter um número binário em decimal?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 2):

Para fazer isso, poderia utilizar a função [`int`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#int). Segundo a documentação, quando utilizamos a função `int` ela possui o segundo parâmetro `base` com o valor default 10. Desta forma se queremos fazer uma conversão de binário para decimal, basta fornecer no primeiro parâmetro a string que representa o valor (em binário) e preencher o segundo parâmetro com o valor correspondente à base do número passado no primeiro parâmetro, para o seu caso será a base 2 (binário).

Segue um exemplo:

```
a = bin(10)
# '0b1010'
int(a,2)
# 10
```

Obs.: Para utilizar essa função não é necessário instalar nenhuma dependência externa, elas são funções da linguagem de programação Python. Uma lista das funções embutidas pode ser vista [`aqui`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html).